# Why does Torbutton circuit view not consistently show the correct exit node?

Tags: exit-relays, circuit, tor-button, tor-browser-bundle

Making an arbitrary number of new identities will eventually cause the circuit view in Torbutton to show the wrong exit node.

[image]

This is a screenshot I took to show the problem. Notice Torbutton thinks my IP address is 104.167.102.244 and in Canada. check.torproject.org says it is 195.154.111.124 Atlas says that exit is in France

This is not related to architecture or OS nor to my network or even to machines owned by me. Also the problem is not limited to check.torproject.org and it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

When testing this I found that the number of new identities that are needed to reproduce this varies. Sometimes it happened first time other times I spent 10-15 minutes creating new identities in order to 'break' circuit view.

This has been happening over multiple versions of Tor Browser and doesn't seem to affect anonymity because the ip addresses are always Tor nodes. So it is **not** 'breaking Tor', just the circuit view.

Is this a known (or unknown) problem with TorButton's circuit view, or have I misconfigured something? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Looks like it's probably a bug. Can't see an existing ticket matching this, though could have missed it.  (I'd file a ticket anyway: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/stem/bugs)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I checked for existing tickets a while ago and couldn't find any either. I will have a chance file a new one next week. Is Stem the right component, not Torbutton?

Comment: Ticket can be found here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18138

Comment: I noticed that there are quite a few nodes in Europe that are not labelled right in TOR browser. I faced it for a long time. Now, I manually check my exit node before connecting to make sure I'm connecting from my preferred country.